# Use ENUM with Sequelize and Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, enums, sequelize.js

I'm trying to create a API with a USER class that can have more then one way of authenticating itself with the API.

I have managed to get it working with 1 user only having 1 credential but when trying to expand to allow multiple credentials then I got error:
`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeDatabaseError: (conn=498, no: 1265, SQLState: 01000) Data truncated for column 'type' at row 1`

What I currently have is this:

```
User.hasMany(Credential, { foreignKey: 'id', sourceKey: 'id' });
```

And this:

```
//Credential.ts
export function CredentialInit(sequelize: Sequelize) {
    let cred = Object.keys(CredentialType);
    let credArr: string[] = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < cred.length/2; i++) {
        credArr.push(`${i}`);
    };
    Credential.init({
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: true
        },
        password: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: true
        },
        token: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: true
        },
        type: {
            type: DataTypes.ENUM,
            values: credArr,
            allowNull: false
        }
    }, {
        sequelize: sequelize,
        tableName: 'credentials'
    });
}

export enum CredentialType {
    EMAIL,
    TOKEN
}

export class Credential extends BaseModel {
    public type!: CredentialType;
    public token?: string;
    public email?: string;
    public password?: string;
}
```

Also have this Model to remove these stuff from all my other models.

```
//BaseModel.ts
export class BaseModel extends Model {
    public id?: number;
    public readonly createdAt?: Date;
    public readonly updatedAt?: Date;
}
```

Any clue why I get this message?
I have written it like this because I do not want to have to declare the content of the enum twice.. If changed I want it to change everywhere....

Comment: why are looping over only ~half of the enum keys?

Comment: The first half is the index of the elements, or the assigned value ('0' ,'1' ) and the second half is the elements string representation('EMAIL', 'TOKEN')

Comment: Realised now that I could have done Object.keys(CredentialType).slice(0,Object.keys(CredentialType)/2) and skipped the for-loop.. Anyway... XD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay so after alot more experimenting I found a way.
Since a enum option is represented as a number in typescript/javascript I changed the database type corresponding to the enum:

```
Credential.init({
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    },
    password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    },
    token: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    },
    type: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    }
}, {
    sequelize: sequelize,
    tableName: 'credentials'
});
```

When it was saved to the database as a integer the error dissolved.

Comment: Or you can use string instead of the number  ```export enum CredentialType {
    EMAIL = "EMAIL",
    TOKEN = "TOKEN"
}```

Answer (score 5):

Since an `enum` in TypeScript is a value, you can spread the `enum` values into the `DataTypes.ENUM` of Sequelize, like this:

```js
enum CredentialType {
  EMAIL,
  TOKEN
}

Credential.init({
  // ...
  type: {
    type: DataTypes.ENUM(...Object.values(CredentialType)),
    allowNull: false
  }
}, {
  sequelize: sequelize,
  tableName: 'credentials'
});
```

Or with the [sequelize-typescript](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-typescript) library, like this:

```js
import { Column, DataType, Model, Table } from "sequelize-typescript";

enum CredentialType {
  EMAIL = "EMAIL",
  TOKEN = "TOKEN",
}

@Table
class Credential extends Model {
  @Column({
    defaultValue: CredentialType.EMAIL,
    type: DataType.ENUM(...Object.values(CredentialType)),
  })
  type!: CredentialType;
}
```

Note, the default values for an `enum` in TypeScript are indexed, but can be overridden with your own values , like this:

```js
enum CredentialType {
  EMAIL = "EMAIL",
  TOKEN = "TOKEN"
}
```